# What is the alternating sum of coefficients and what does it have to do with the zeroes of the function?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, indefinite-integrals

So, my teacher told us today, while we were solving this integral: $$\int\frac{dx}{x(2x^3+x^2+1)}$$ that the alternating sum of coefficients of $2x^3+x^2+1$ is 0 (2-1+0-1=0) and hence, one zero of the function is $-1$. Why is the zero $-1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This method can be used to check whether $-1$ is a root. If you plug $-1$ into a polynomial, you are actually adding the coefficients with alternating signs. That is because odd power of $-1$ is $-1$ and even power of $-1$ is $1$. So if you add alternating coefficients and get $0$, it means $-1$ is a root.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very non-rigorous way of developing the intuition behind Descartes' Rule of Signs.

Let $P(x)=2x^3+x^2+1$.  For $x\ge 0$, $P(x)>0$.

For values of $x<<-1$, the leading term $2x^3$ dominates the quadratic and constant terms.  $P$ decreases without bound and we must have a point $x_N$ for which $P(x)<0$ for all $x<x_N$ .

Since $P$ always increases, is greater than zero when $x>0$, is less than zero when $x<<-1$, then there must be one and only one point $x_0 <0$ for which $P(x_0)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$2x^3+x^2+1=(x+1)(2x^2-x+1)$$
and $2x^2-x+1\neq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. Therefore, the only zero of $x(2x^3+x^2+1)$ are $0$ and $-1$.